# How to collect information from SQL Server table and use it in INSERT-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have this `INSERT` statement in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO [UserClassSettings]
       ([RSRC]
       ,[Deleted]
       ,[DateNew]
       ,[DateChanged]
       ,[UserNew]
       ,[UserChanged]
       ,[ProgramID]
       ,[UserID]
       ,[ClassName]
       ,[WriteByOpen]
       ,[DefaultReadAccess]
       ,[DefaultWriteAccess]
       ,[Summary])
 VALUES
       (0
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,NULL
       ,(SELECT ProgramID FROM [User] where UserName='Andreas')
       ,NULL
       ,NEWID()
       ,(SELECT UserID FROM [User] where UserName='Andreas')
       ,'RootOrder_C'
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0)
GO
```

Now I want to use this `INSERT` statement not only for Andreas but for every user. Users are in the table "User". So, I need to collect all Users from the `User` table and use it as a variable.

So that it looks like this

```
,(SELECT ProgramID FROM [User] where UserName=@user)
,(SELECT UserID FROM [User] where UserName=@user)
```

If this is possible to do this in SQL.

Maybe like this:

```
DECLARE @user int
DECLARE @anzahl int = (select count(*) from user)
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < @anzahl BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    print @i
    -- INSERT?
END
```

My question is:

Is this possible to do in SQL and if yes how can I do that?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert result set from `SELECT` query like this

```
INSERT INTO [UserClassSettings]
       ([RSRC]
       ,[Deleted]
       ,[DateNew]
       ,[DateChanged]
       ,[UserNew]
       ,[UserChanged]
       ,[ProgramID]
       ,[UserID]
       ,[ClassName]
       ,[WriteByOpen]
       ,[DefaultReadAccess]
       ,[DefaultWriteAccess]
       ,[Summary])
SELECT
        0
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,NULL
       ,ProgramID
       ,NULL
       ,NEWID()
       ,UserID 
       ,'RootOrder_C'
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
       ,0
FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
UPDATE UserClassSettings 
SET RSRC = 0, Deleted = 0, DateNew = GETDATE(), ......
WHERE UserID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM User )
```